# How to handle custom_attributes from REST API data?

Tags: magento2, api, json

When dealing with the Magento v2 API, I faced a problem where getting product details have inconsistent data from REST API.

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

These are Note 8 and iPhone 8 data and we can see that the custom_attributes[10] is having different attribute code.
The Note 8's custom_attrbutes[10] is url_key.
The iPhone 8's custom_attributes[10] is country_of_manufacture.

Can i have some suggestions how to handle this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to a different structure with the attribute codes as keys. How exactly depends on which language you are using to process the result.

In JavaScript you can use `reduce`:

```
var input = [
    {'attribute_code' : 'meta_title', 'value' : 'lorem'},
    {'attribute_code' : 'meta_keyword', 'value' : 'ipsum'},
];

var customAttributes = input.reduce(function(result, item) {
    result[item.attribute_code] = item.value;
    return result;
}, {});
```

This code creates an object by walking through all array items in `input` (the `custom_attributes` result from the API) and applying a function on it.

Comment: Isn't there anyway to get this directly in the result by altering the request? Something like `/rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku,price,name,custom_attributes[my_custom_field]]` (I know this doesn't work, it's an example)